# Powering the PixHawk with USB on the "Power” port

Tags: flight-controller

I was wondering if it is possible to power a pixhawk with an USB cable (power from a powerbank) via its "Power" port. Something like a DF13 to USB cable, maybe with a DIY cable. I just need the power (+5V and GND) without A and V reading because I am using the pixhawk not to control a multicopter but just to geotag some images taken with a FLIR thermocamera attached to PixHawk.

The flight controller is a RadioLink MiniPix:

http://radiolink.com.cn/doce/product-detail-169.html